# Save key value in two different variables

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure out a way to split a string by delimiter `:` and save it as two strings. I tried something in line 9, but it is not working. I want to find existence of `@clients` in `@ping_host`. If it does not exist, then send an alert. Any suggestion?

```
@ping_host = ['1232','1212'];
@clients = ['1232:RARB','1212:CBN'];
client_monitor_state(@ping_host);

sub client_monitor_state(@ping_host){
 my $token = $properties{token};
 @clients = split(/,/, $token);
 foreach $client (@clients){
 ($client_id,$client_name)=m/(\w+)\s*:(.+)/;  # here the client_id should have the first part of match string
 
  if(! grep($client_id,@ping_host)){
   print "Client noted is $client_name \n";
   # mail the client that is not reachable
   my $subject_line = "The client $client_name is not reachable";
   smtp_send(server_name => $client_name, subject_name => $subject_line);
  }  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `use warnings;` because it would probably have hinted at the solution.  You are implicitly using `$_` instead of `$client`, and you need to use `=~` instead of `=`

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $client = 'this:that';
my ($client_id, $client_name) = $client =~ m/(\w+)\s*:(.+)/;
print "$client_id,$client_name\n";
```

Output:

```
this,that
```